# ng-repeat duplicates ng-click function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so I created a button to open a calendar with an ng-click function:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="main.open_date()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
</button>
```

I put it inside an ng-repeat, and when I added more fields & tested the button, this happened:

[image]

Aren't rows created by `ng-repeat` unique because they have their own index?
What am I missing here?

update: here is the code for my main.open_date():

```
me.open_date = function(key){
    if(!key){key='date';}
    me.uibdates[key] = true;
}
```

template code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in main.employee_details track by $index">
    <td>
        <ui-select ng-model="detail.status" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select status" allow-clear>{$$select.selected.name$}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="status in main.status | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} | limitTo: 100">
                <div ng-bind-html="status.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                          ng-click="main.open_date()">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                  </button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select date"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
                   ng-model="detail.date" is-open="main.uibdates['date']" 
                   ng-change="main.date_change()" />
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.remark" placeholder="">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button style="display: inline; width: 35px;"class="form-control btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="main.add_field($index);" ng-if="$index == (main.employee_details.length - 1)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        <button style="display: inline; width: 35px;" class="form-control btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="main.delete_field($index);" ng-if="main.employee_details.length != 1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you include the whole template including the `ng-repeat` section, and also it will be easy to understand if the controller code was also there.

Comment: @Senal here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my imagine, you can customize your code:
HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in listItems track by item.id + $index">
        <input class="datetime-picker" id="datepicker_{{item.id}}" />
        <button ng-click="main.open_date(item.id)" class="open-datetime-picker">Open</button>
    </div>
```

Angularjs

```
    main.open_date = function(id){
        $("datepicker_" + id).datetimepicker();
    }
```

Comment: yeah I tried doing something similar to this, and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside the ng-repeat are repeated except the index. If you didn't use the index, the button is not unique.

Comment: Please post the code. I don't understant why the button should be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

in function main.open_date()  can you use id instead class or html tags

like this

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you add $index in ng-repeat? Example: <div ng-repeat="item in listItems track by $index"></div>

Or, if your item have an ID field: <div ng-repeat="item in listItems track by item.id + $index"></div>

Comment: So, I think the problem is in datepicker render and function main.open_date().
Can you show me your HTML and code of function main.open_date() ?